# How to set entire ListView row color / eliminate space between ListView rows?

Tags: .net, wpf, listview

I'd like to change the background color of ListView rows individually. I have been able to do so, but there is two pixels of whiteness between each row. I want to eliminate the white space so that when two rows have the same color, there is no visible division between them.

[image: ListView screenshot]

Plus, when a row is selected or moused-over, its background color is hidden. Can I make it visible again?

Example code (in my real code I select the color through data binding):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <!--Doesn't help!-->
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Date" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Day Of Week"  
           DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Year" 
           DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
            <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
            <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
            <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine, rows are without gaps. You can try setting negative margin for ListView.ItemContainerStyle anyway.
What do you meen by hidden background? Selected row is highlighted, but when deselected it returns to previous state.

Comment: I mean that when an item is highlighted, the user can't see what color it is. It would be much better to show the selection rectangle only, or blend it with the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the whitespace you mention you need to use a negative margin of `0,-2,0,0`. If that does not work, then you may need to look deeper at the `GridViewPresenter` for a margin/padding property.

Also, get yourself a copy of **Snoop** from Codeplex (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It is absolutely essential for *any* WPF development.

Comment: Thanks, it hadn't occurred to me to try negative numbers. I decided to use Margin "0 -1 0 -1" for evenness. According to icebat this doesn't happen on all computers, so I tried to compensate for the spacing change with Padding "0 1 0 1" in the style, but apparently Padding has no effect on ListViewItem.

Comment: The reason why it does not happen on all computers is because the defaults for *each* Windows theme is different, e.g., Aero, Classic, Luna (XP) etc.

Comment: I was able to adjust the padding, using a TextBlock in a DataTemplate in the CellTemplate of one of the GridViewColumns. In order to retain the color on a selected item, I set the TextBlock's background instead (which works because this background is drawn on top of the selection rect), using colors with Opacity<0.5 so that the selection rectangle is still visible. This means that only one column is colored, but it's enough for me. Oddly I had to increase the margin by two more pixels because another gap appeared between rows... and the selection rect looks a bit odd... but whatever.

Comment: Using negative margins is an excellent way (sometimes the only way) to achieve a certain look. I was first uncertain about if it was 'best-practice' as usually against using *magic* numbers, however they are very useful to pull-things back into alignment and create overlapping (e.g. if you had a border on a `ListBoxItem` to prevent a double-border effect you could use a `0,-1,0,0` margin to pull it up one pixel).